# Having trouble making image grid stack correctly responsively. There are two columns stacking incorrectly

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I'm trying to make this image grid stack at responsively at 33.33% at 1224px and 50% at 720px and lower. I think I'm missing something in the CSS, but I'm fairly new so I'd really appreciate if someone could help out.

I want to make sure that the client logos on the page stack on mobile, tablet, etc. At the moment, two of the columns start to overlap when the window is minimized. It seems that, because one of the columns only contains 3 images and the others contain 4, for some reason the three-image column isn't following the CSS rules I've created.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Here's what I've got:

```css
/* five column GRID STYLES
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

.column {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.column {
  width: 20%;
}

.item:last-child {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1224px) {
  /* 10 columns for larger screens */
  .column {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .column:last-child {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  /* 10 columns for larger screens */
  .column {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .column:last-child {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  /* 10 columns for larger screens */
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

.image:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="column">
    <a href="https://www.theorthodoc.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.smiles4acure.com/images/Busciglio_S4AC.png" style="width:100%"></a>

    <a href="https://canalesortho.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.smiles4acure.com/images/Canales_S4AC.png" style="width:100%"></a>

    <a href="https://chadwellsmiles.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.smiles4acure.com/images/Chadwell_S4AC.png" style="width:100%"></a>

    <a href="https://www.embraceyoursmile.us/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.smiles4acure.com/images/Culberson_S4AC.png" style="width:100%"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <a href="https://eckleyorthodontics.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.smiles4acure.com/images/Eckley_S4AC.png" style="width:100%"></a>

    <a href="https://www.fritzorthodontics.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.smiles4acure.com/images/Fritz_S4AC.png" style="width:100%"></a>

    <a href="http://www.pittmanortho.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.smiles4acure.com/images/Pittman_S4AC.png" style="width:100%"></a>

    <a href="https://tlortho.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.smiles4acure.com/images/logos_pin_seperate.png" style="width:100%"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <a href="https://grafortho.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.smiles4acure.com/images/Graf_S4AC.png" style="width:100%"></a>

    <a href="https://www.hassfamilyorthodontics.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.smiles4acure.com/images/Hass_S4AC.png" style="width:100%"></a>

    <a href="http://www.hatcherorthodontics.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.smiles4acure.com/images/Hatcher_S4AC.png" style="width:100%"></a>

    <a href="https://www.harveyandthomasortho.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.smiles4acure.com/images/HT_S4AC.png" style="width:100%"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <a href="https://www.tkoenortho.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.smiles4acure.com/images/Koen_S4AC.png" style="width:100%"></a>

    <a href="https://limbaughortho.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.smiles4acure.com/images/Limbaugh_S4AC.png" style="width:100%"></a>

    <a href="https://mckoenortho.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.smiles4acure.com/images/MCK_S4AC.png" style="width:100%"></a>

    <a href="https://celebrating-smiles.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.smiles4acure.com/images/Paciorek_S4AC.png" style="width:100%"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <a href="https://herrmannorthodontics.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.smiles4acure.com/images/Rick_Herrmann_S4AC.png" style="width:100%"></a>

    <a href="https://simsorthodontics.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.smiles4acure.com/images/Sims_S4AC.png" style="width:100%"></a>

    <a href="https://www.tariorthodontics.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.smiles4acure.com/images/Tari_S4AC.png" style="width:100%"></a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Flexbox* and *Viewport*, here's some guides at W3Schools if you want to try: 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp